# Error creating entityManagerFactory due to error tying to scan <jar-file>

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am following http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/3 ; I am not
 sure what I did wrong, but I keep on getting exceptions that I don't understand. I tried searching for questions with the same exceptions to no avail.

**Stack trace:**
http://pastebin.com/WYPqS6da

PersistenceConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() throws SQLException {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan("com.scrumster.persistence.domain");
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'tomcat'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'propdeps'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-maven'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-idea'
apply plugin: 'propdeps-eclipse'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url "http://download.java.net/maven/2"
    }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release' }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'org.gradle.api.plugins:gradle-tomcat-plugin:0.9.8'
    classpath 'org.springframework.build.gradle:propdeps-plugin:0.0.1'
  }
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone/'}
}

dependencies {
    def tomcatVersion = '7.0.42'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
            "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:${tomcatVersion}"
    tomcat("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}") {
      exclude group: 'org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler', module: 'ecj'
    }

    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.5.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.3.4.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.0.1.Final'
    compile 'org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:0.7.0.RELEASE'
    compile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:0.8.1'

    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.0.M2'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M2'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.0.M2'

    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    runtime 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.2'
    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.5'
    runtime 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.3'
    runtime 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.9'

    provided 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1'

    testCompile 'com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path-assert:0.8.1'
    testCompile 'org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.5.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"

}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.12'
}

tomcatRunWar.contextPath = ''
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while reading file:/E:/Files/Source/Workspace-Eclipse2/scrumster/bin/
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getFilesInJar(NativeScanner.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:503)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:851)
        ... 58 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1113)
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1056)
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:150)
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:765)
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:109)
```

I hope someone could point me to the right source, or help me in this predicament.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The error:

```
invalid constant type: 18
```

Indicates that you have built the Jars with Java 8, but are attempting to run the application in a lower version.

From what I have seen elsewhere, you probably need to switch to a newer version of javassist (which is raising the error), as the version you are using is not compatible with Java 8.

Comment: See my additional edit - the problem is not so much the runtime as the fact that you are using an incompatible library (javassist). It does bytecode manipulation, so it's more sensitive to JVM versions than most.

Comment: I suspect that it's a transitive dependency brought in by one of the dependencies found in your build.gradle. I know that the Eclipse pom.xml editor will show where dependencies have come from. Unfortunately I don't use Gradle very often, so I'm not sure whether similar tools are provided.

Comment: I tried reducing compliance level of project to Java 7 (instead of updating some of my things), and still not working for me.

Comment: Same error? The stack trace you provided tells me that something in `E:/Files/Source/Workspace-Eclipse2/scrumster/bin/` was built using Java 8.

Comment: It seems converting it to Java 7 corrected the issue. Thanks.

Comment: It's running Java 8... This is my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900070/maven-cannot-build-java-8

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem while migrating one of my projects to Java 8. Fixed it by updating the hibernate-entitymanager artifact version from 4.2.0.Final to 4.3.8.Final.

Answer (score 8):

If you use 3.6.10-Final you need exclude javassist (without **org.** prefix)

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
       <!-- javassist with fixed https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JASSIST-174 -->
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Working for me with hibernate-entitymanager version `3.6.0.Final`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to provide beans for EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager.
Just provide a bean LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

Comment: Hi, I'm quite new with Spring. Can you expound on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. My problem was that I had another dependency (in my case jboss weld) that used different version of javassist. Excluding did not help.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

So, above exclusion does not work. I had to find a workaround for jboss weld.