# org.reflections.Reflections cannot find my class (in relation the way I'm writing my lambda)

Tags: java, reflection, lambda, java-8, reflections

I'm working with [GATK](https://software.broadinstitute.org/gatk/), a java tool for bioinformatics. It use org.reflections.Reflections under the hood to load some plugins.

My plugin compiled but wasn't found/loaded by GATK while it was in the classpath and a similar tool was working without any problem. By removing some part of the code, I've narrowed the problem to the following line which was the cause of my problem (see **filter** ) :

```
(...)
ctx.getAlleles().stream().filter(T->!(T.isSymbolic() || T.isNoCall())).mapToInt(new ToIntFunction<Allele>() {
    public int applyAsInt(Allele value) {return value.length();};
    });
(...)
```

**My plugin is loaded** if I change the line above  to :

```
(...)
ctx.getAlleles().stream().mapToInt(new ToIntFunction<Allele>() {
        public int applyAsInt(Allele value) {return value.length();};
    });
(...)
```

**It's also loaded**  if the line is:

```
final Predicate<Allele> afilter = new Predicate<Allele>() {
    @Override
    public boolean test(Allele a) {
        return !(a.isNoCall() || a.isSymbolic());
    }
};
ctx.getAlleles().stream().filter(afilter).mapToInt(new ToIntFunction<Allele>() {
        public int applyAsInt(Allele value) {return value.length();};
    });
```

why ?

Comment: Most likely, because that tool is incompatible with Java 8, indicated by the fact that it stops working as soon as you are using a lambda expression.

Comment: Incompatibilities between Reflections and Java 8 were already reported [back in May 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30313255/2711488), but looking at the [open issues on GitHub](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues), it seems, they still haven’t resolved. Note especially [this one](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/150) from Oct 2016, confirmed in Dec 2016…