# Adding mock breaks database tests

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, testng, hsqldb

I have googled everything that I can think of to no avail. I am running with Spring 4.3.1.

I have inherited an app and am trying to beef the unit tests back up to be useful.

As part of this, I added the following line to a unit test:

```
Mockito.when(udfConfigurationRepository.save(any(UDFConfiguration.class))).thenAnswer(parm -> parm.getArguments()[0]);
```

The unit test worked fine. I then ran a build for the app and got the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:138)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:175)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:107)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao-test.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: file:/C:/casenet/Sources/provider-portal/portal-server/target/test-classes
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: file:/C:/casenet/Sources/provider-portal/portal-server/target/test-classes
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:855)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.java:50)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while reading file:/C:/casenet/Sources/provider-portal/portal-server/target/test-classes
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getClassesInJar(NativeScanner.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:852)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1113)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1056)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:150)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:765)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.checkAnnotationMatching(AbstractJarVisitor.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.executeJavaElementFilter(AbstractJarVisitor.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.addElement(AbstractJarVisitor.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.ExplodedJarVisitor.getClassNamesInTree(ExplodedJarVisitor.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.ExplodedJarVisitor.getClassNamesInTree(ExplodedJarVisitor.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.ExplodedJarVisitor.getClassNamesInTree(ExplodedJarVisitor.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.ExplodedJarVisitor.getClassNamesInTree(ExplodedJarVisitor.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.ExplodedJarVisitor.getClassNamesInTree(ExplodedJarVisitor.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.ExplodedJarVisitor.getClassNamesInTree(ExplodedJarVisitor.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.ExplodedJarVisitor.doProcessElements(ExplodedJarVisitor.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.getMatchingEntries(AbstractJarVisitor.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getClassesInJar(NativeScanner.java:128)
    ... 52 more
```

This error re-occurred on all of the tests that actually test out the repository through Spring. The only thing I can think of is that by mocking this repo, it's gummed up the works for Spring.

All the database tests inherit from this base class.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/applicationContext-dao-test.xml" })
@Transactional
@TestExecutionListeners( { TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class })
public class BaseRepositoryTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests{
    public BaseRepositoryTest(){ super(); }
}
```

And here is applicationContext-dao-test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jpa = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:p = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:component-scan  base-package="com.casenet.portals.repository" />
    <context:component-scan  base-package="com.casenet.portals.services" />

    <jpa:repositories base-package = "com.casenet.portals.repository"/>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="portalDataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.casenet.portals.repository</value>
                <value>com.casenet.portals.domain</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql:false}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql:false}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence-test.xml" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="casenet" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="portalDataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="portalDataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
          p:driverClassName="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"
          p:url="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:casenetApplication;sql.enforce_strict_size=true"
          p:username="sa"
          p:password="" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

Again all of these test fail now and the only change is the one line mocking my repository.

I have a feeling this has something to do with contexts and that I can fix it that way, but can't seem to find the proper way to go about separating these.

Comment: As I can see from the stacktrace there must be something different, have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313255/reflections-java-8-invalid-constant-type already?

Comment: @mrkernelpanic Wow! Excellent call! Would you like to write an answer so that I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, the answer lies with [Reflections - Java 8 - invalid constant type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313255/reflections-java-8-invalid-constant-type).

It turns out that constant: 18 refers to an issue when using java 8 style lambdas with libraries not compiled under java 8.

So to fix the issue, I had to write more code as follows:

```
Mockito.when(udfConfigurationRepository.save(any(UDFConfiguration.class))).thenAnswer(new Answer<UDFConfiguration>() {
        @Override
        public UDFConfiguration answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
            UDFConfiguration config = (UDFConfiguration) invocationOnMock.getArguments()[0];
            return config;
        }
    });
```

Doing so fixed this unit test and all of the others.