# Upgrade to Java 8 causes Orika mapper in unittest java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15 at 142

Tags: java, java-8, orika

I have a project that I want to update the version from Java 1.7 to Java 1.8  but running the UnitTests all mapper tests are failing.

The project is using:
SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
    <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

For that part of the exception: `nested exception is ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15 at 142`
I found u.a this SO post:
[Reflections - Java 8 - invalid constant type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313255/reflections-java-8-invalid-constant-type)
But I'm not sure if this is realy the problem, as I have no dependency on the 'javassist'.

Is this related to the same issue?
How can I overcome that?

More complete StackTrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.company.APP.common.mapping.orika.configuration.mappers.user.UserMapperTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFacade com.company.APP.common.mapping.orika.configuration.mappers.BaseMapperTest.mapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapperFacadeFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15 at 142

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:385)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:199)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:253)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected ma.glasnost.orika.MapperFacade com.company.APP.common.mapping.orika.configuration.mappers.BaseMapperTest.mapper; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapperFacadeFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15 at 142
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 25 more
...
...
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15 at 142
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1044)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:984)
    at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:125)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:770)
    at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:114)
    at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:191)
    ... 79 more
```

Comment: If you didn't have a dependency on `javassist`, it wouldn't be in your classpath. Spring depends on indirectly (transitively). The link you posted is correct: You're using an old version of `javassist` and you need to update to a newer version, or stay on Java 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea goes into the right direction.

the `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 15 at 142` 
shows that the the application has problems with java 8 - as explained inn your link.

The ma.glasnost.orika mapper depends on javassist as you can see in the Stack Trace.
This is a transitive dependency of orika.

You could use `mvn dependency:tree -verbose` to build a dependency tree. 
There you can look up the what library is depending eg on javassist and the exact version.

To use a javassist version that is Java 8 compatible use that dependency to overwrite the implicit dependency of orika:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
  </dependency>
```

But for this example it might by better to upgrade the orika version to 1.4.6 as this one is Java 8 ready.