# There is error message when added @Entity from another application-module?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, websphere

spring-application deployed on Webshere8.5.5.13
I used spring 4.0.1 version and hibernate 4.0.1.Final
So, there are any modules in application
Parent(is a root of application) and modules webapp and common
webapp use dependecies of common

common.pom

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>rs.MyApp</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyApp-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${MyApp.version}</version>
        <relativePath>../MyApp-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>MyApp-common</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MyApp-common</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.3.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch>3.0.8.RELEASE</spring.batch>
        <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
        <spring.test>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.test>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <compress>true</compress>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>libs/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/libs</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!--SPRING-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--SPRING-BATCH(for migration data)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch}</version>
            <exclusions>
               ...
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--WEB-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--DATABASE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.odb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--JPA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.9.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>uow</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--APACHE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--LOG4J-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and pom of webapp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
            http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>rs.SBDataServices</groupId>
        <artifactId>MyApp-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${MyApp.version}</version>
        <relativePath>../MyApp-parent/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>MyApp-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>MyApp-webapp</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.3.13.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch>3.0.8.RELEASE</spring.batch>
        <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
        <spring.test>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.test>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>MyApp</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!--SPRING-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--SPRING-BATCH(for migration data)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--WEB-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--DATABASE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.odb</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>12.1.0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--JPA-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.9.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.websphere</groupId>
            <artifactId>uow</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--APACHE-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--TEST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--LOG4J-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>rs.SBDataServices</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyApp-common</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

So, I compile app and start, everything is okey.
Than, I try to move @Entity class from webapp to common module, and there is erorr messages in logs, Application fails to start

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan
>   :
>   file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Node01/installedApps/Cell01/MyApp.ear/MyApp-webapp-CURRENT.war/WEB-INF/lib/MyApp-common-8.0.5.jar

and

```
java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
```

So, I tried to exclude old versions of javassist from my app and add javassist that maintain for java8
I tried to enable parent last mode on server, and server didn't start too.

My class persistence

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"persistence", "zashita"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "data.persistence",
        "zashita"
})
public class PersistenceConfig {
    private static final String[] PACKAGE_WITH_JPA_ENTITIES = {
            "data.persistence",
            "zashita"
    };
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Bean
    @Resource(type = DataSource.class, lookup = "jdbc/MYAPP", name = "jdbc/MYAPP")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/MYAPP");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_WITH_JPA_ENTITIES);
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        log.info("Entity Manager configured..");
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Set properties hibernate
     * To create tables not via Goblin, use
     * properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
     *
     * @return
     */
    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field", false);

        properties.put("verifyServerCertificate", false);
        properties.put("useSSL", false);
        properties.put("requireSSL", false);
        properties.put("useLegacyDatetimeCode", false);
        properties.put("useUnicode", "yes");
        properties.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
        properties.put("serverTimezone", "UTC");
        properties.put("useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.archive.autodetection", "class,hbm");
        properties.put("exclude-unlisted-classes", false);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

and my class which try to move

```
package zashita;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    private String objectId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public String getObjectId() {
        return objectId;
    }

    public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a chance you're affected by [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313255/reflections-java-8-invalid-constant-type)?

Comment: @crizzis the error message is same, but root cause is different I think