# IOException when using classes from another module

Tags: java, spring, maven, ioexception

How to use classes from one module in other? There are two java-modules common and webapp with java-classes, so I need use in webapp module classes from common
In common I build war file and there is my pom.xml

```
       <build>
        <finalName>SBRiskDataSvcs</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    <classesClassifier>classes</classesClassifier>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
```

Webapp module use common like dependency like this

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.sberbank.rs.SBDataServices</groupId>
        <artifactId>SBRiskDataSvcs-common</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

But, when try to start application, there is error message

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
```

the full logs are

> [1/23/20 18:19:33:605 MSK] 000000fc SystemOut     O WARN: Please see
>   http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#release for an explanation. [1/23/20
>   18:19:33:617 MSK] 000000fc CompositionUn E   WSVR0194E: Composition
>   unit WebSphere:cuname=MyApplication in BLA
>   WebSphere:blaname=MyApplication failed to start. [1/23/20 18:19:33:631
>   MSK] 000000ba AdminHelper   A   ADMN1009I: An attempt is made to start
>   the MyApplication application. [1/23/20 18:19:33:643 MSK] 000000ba
>   CompositionUn A   WSVR0190I: Starting composition unit
>   WebSphere:cuname=MyApplication in BLA WebSphere:blaname=MyApplication.
>   [1/23/20 18:19:39:417 MSK] 000000ba ApplicationMg A   WSVR0200I:
>   Starting application: MyApplication [1/23/20 18:19:39:420 MSK]
>   000000ba ApplicationMg A   WSVR0204I: Application: MyApplication 
>   Application build level: Unknown [1/23/20 18:19:39:596 MSK] 000000ba
>   SibMessage    I   [:] CWSID0017I: Configuration reload is starting for
>   bus RSKbus. [1/23/20 18:19:39:606 MSK] 000000ba SibMessage    I   [:]
>   CWSID0018I: Configuration reload is complete for bus RSKbus. [1/23/20
>   18:19:39:611 MSK] 000000ba SibMessage    I   [:] CWSID0019I:
>   Configuration reload is starting for messaging engine
>   Cluster1.000-RSKbus. [1/23/20 18:19:39:615 MSK] 000000ba SibMessage
>   I   [:] CWSID0020I: Configuration reload is complete for messaging
>   engine Cluster1.000-RSKbus. [1/23/20 18:19:41:368 MSK] 000000ba webapp
>   I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl WebGroup SRVE0169I:
>   Loading Web Module: MyApplication-webapp-CURRENT.war. [1/23/20
>   18:19:41:391 MSK] 000000ba WASSessionCor I SessionContextRegistry
>   getSessionContext SESN0176I: Will create a new session context for
>   application key default_host/MyApplication [1/23/20 18:19:52:694 MSK]
>   000000ba webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log
>   SRVE0292I: Servlet Message -
>   [MyApplication#MyApplication-webapp-CURRENT.war]:.1 Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath [1/23/20 18:19:52:699
>   MSK] 000000ba SystemOut     O [2020-01-23 18:19:52.698] INFO 
>   config.WebAppInitalizer                  WebApp launching.. [1/23/20
>   18:19:52:826 MSK] 000000ba SystemOut     O [2020-01-23 18:19:52.826]
>   INFO  config.WebAppInitalizer                  WebApp started..
>   [1/23/20 18:19:52:827 MSK] 000000ba webapp        I
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message -
>   [MyApplication#MyApplication-webapp-CURRENT.war]:.Initializing Spring
>   root WebApplicationContext [1/23/20 18:19:52:828 MSK] 000000ba
>   SystemOut     O [2020-01-23 18:19:52.828] INFO 
>   pringframework.web.context.ContextLoader Root WebApplicationContext:
>   initialization started [1/23/20 18:19:52:869 MSK] 000000ba SystemOut
>   O [2020-01-23 18:19:52.869] INFO 
>   rt.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext Refreshing Root
>   WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Jan 23 18:19:52 MSK 2020];
>   root of context hierarchy [1/23/20 18:19:53:020 MSK] 000000ba
>   SystemOut     O [2020-01-23 18:19:53.020] INFO 
>   rt.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext Registering annotated
>   classes: [class mypackage.web.WebConfig,class
>   mypackage.service.ServiceConfig,class
>   mypackage.persistence.PersistenceConfig] [1/23/20 18:19:53:782 MSK]
>   000000ba SystemOut     O [2020-01-23 18:19:53.782] INFO 
>   ctory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory Overriding bean definition
>   for bean 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' with a different definition:
>   replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false;
>   lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0;
>   autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration;
>   factoryMethodName=requestMappingHandlerMapping; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration]
>   with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false;
>   autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true;
>   primary=false; factoryBeanName=webConfig;
>   factoryMethodName=requestMappingHandlerMapping; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in mypackage.web.WebConfig]
>   [1/23/20 18:19:54:496 MSK] 000000ba SystemOut     O [2020-01-23
>   18:19:54.496] INFO  ion.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor JSR-330
>   'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
>   [1/23/20 18:19:55:025 MSK] 000000ba SystemOut     O [2020-01-23
>   18:19:55.025] INFO  eConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a25b9480 Entity
>   Manager configured.. [1/23/20 18:19:55:101 MSK] 000000ba SystemOut
>   O [2020-01-23 18:19:55.101] INFO 
>   a.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean Building JPA container
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default' [1/23/20
>   18:19:55:387 MSK] 000000ba SystemOut     O [2020-01-23 18:19:55.387]
>   INFO  org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version HCANN000001: Hibernate
>   Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final} [1/23/20 18:19:55:403 MSK] 000000ba
>   SystemOut     O [2020-01-23 18:19:55.403] INFO  org.hibernate.Version 
>   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final} [1/23/20 18:19:55:409 MSK]
>   000000ba SystemOut     O [2020-01-23 18:19:55.409] INFO 
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found [1/23/20 18:19:55:413 MSK] 000000ba
>   SystemOut     O [2020-01-23 18:19:55.413] INFO 
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            HHH000021: Bytecode provider
>   name : javassist [1/23/20 18:19:55:478 MSK] 000000ba SystemOut     O
>   [2020-01-23 18:19:55.478] INFO  org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration
>   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
>           name: default
>           ...] [1/23/20 18:19:55:535 MSK] 000000ba SystemOut     O [2020-01-23 18:19:55.535] WARN 
>   rt.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext Exception encountered during
>   context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in
>   mypackage.persistence.PersistenceConfig: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying
>   to scan :
>   file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Node01/installedApps/Cell01/MyApplication.ear/MyApplication-webapp-CURRENT.war/WEB-INF/lib/MyApplication-common-8.0.5-classes.jar [1/23/20 18:19:55:546 MSK] 000000ba SystemOut     O [2020-01-23
>   18:19:55.540] ERROR pringframework.web.context.ContextLoader Context
>   initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in
>   mypackage.persistence.PersistenceConfig: Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying
>   to scan :
>   file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Node01/installedApps/Cell01/MyApplication.ear/MyApplication-webapp-CURRENT.war/WEB-INF/lib/MyApplication-common-8.0.5-classes.jar

```
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Node01/installedApps/Cell01/MyApplication.ear/MyApplication-webapp-CURRENT.war/WEB-INF/lib/MyApplication-common-8.0.5-classes.jar
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:596)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.java:50)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
        ... 70 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while reading file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Node01/installedApps/Cell01/MyApplication.ear/MyApplication-webapp-CURRENT.war/WEB-INF/lib/MyApplication-common-8.0.5-classes.jar
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getFilesInJar(NativeScanner.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:503)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:851)
        ... 78 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1090)
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1033)
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:149)
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:737)
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.checkAnnotationMatching(AbstractJarVisitor.java:245)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getFilesInJar(NativeScanner.java:190)
        ... 80 more [1/23/20 18:19:55:547 MSK] 000000ba webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in mypackage.persistence.PersistenceConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Node01/installedApps/Cell01/MyApplication.ear/MyApplication-webapp-CURRENT.war/WEB-INF/lib/MyApplication-common-8.0.5-classes.jar
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan <jar-file>: file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Node01/installedApps/Cell01/MyApplication.ear/MyApplication-webapp-CURRENT.war/WEB-INF/lib/MyApplication-common-8.0.5-classes.jar
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:854)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:596)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.java:50)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
        ... 70 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while reading file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/Node01/installedApps/Cell01/MyApplication.ear/MyApplication-webapp-CURRENT.war/WEB-INF/lib/MyApplication-common-8.0.5-classes.jar
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getFilesInJar(NativeScanner.java:193)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addScannedEntries(Ejb3Configuration.java:503)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.scanForClasses(Ejb3Configuration.java:851)
        ... 78 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1090)
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1033)
        at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:149)
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:737)
        at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.checkAnnotationMatching(AbstractJarVisitor.java:245)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.executeJavaElementFilter(AbstractJarVisitor.java:211)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.addElement(AbstractJarVisitor.java:172)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.FileZippedJarVisitor.doProcessElements(FileZippedJarVisitor.java:123)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.AbstractJarVisitor.getMatchingEntries(AbstractJarVisitor.java:148)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.NativeScanner.getFilesInJar(NativeScanner.java:190)
        ... 80 more

[1/23/20 18:19:55:554 MSK] 000000ba webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [MyApplication#MyApplication-webapp-CURRENT.war]:.Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

PersistenceConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"mypackage.persistence"})
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"mypackage.persistence", "persistence"})
public class PersistenceConfig {
    private static final String[] PACKAGE_WITH_JPA_ENTITIES = {
            "mypackage.persistence",
            "persistence"
    };

    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(getClass());

    @Bean
    @Resource(type = DataSource.class, lookup = "jdbc/DATA", name = "jdbc/DATA")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("java:comp/env/jdbc/DATA");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGE_WITH_JPA_ENTITIES);
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        log.info("Entity Manager configured..");
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    private Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "none");
        properties.put("org.hibernate.envers.do_not_audit_optimistic_locking_field", false);

        properties.put("verifyServerCertificate", false);
        properties.put("useSSL", false);
        properties.put("requireSSL", false);
        properties.put("useLegacyDatetimeCode", false);
        properties.put("useUnicode", "yes");
        properties.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
        properties.put("serverTimezone", "UTC");
        properties.put("useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift", true);
        return properties;
    }
}
```

this class located in webapp module.

Comment: It seems to be failing in creating entityManager defined in mypackage.persistence.PersistenceConfig class, some property is missing. You may add your PersistenceConfig class to be more specific to problem.

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in mypackage.persistence.PersistenceConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: error trying to scan :

Comment: @Vivek updated issue(added PersistenceConfig.class)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reflections - Java 8 - invalid constant type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313255/reflections-java-8-invalid-constant-type)

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I tried to use 3.24.1-GA and 3.18.0-GA alredy, but it didn't help