# org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15

Tags: spring, java-8

Getting following error while run spring application

> org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
>       at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
>       at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.(ConstantPool.java:45)
>       at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:186)
>       at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:131)
>       at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:323)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:390)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:373)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.ltw.LTWWorld.resolveDelegate(LTWWorld.java:111)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:452)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:298)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:211)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:95)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:41)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureGenericSignatureUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:807)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.getDeclaredInterfaces(BcelObjectType.java:255)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredInterfaces(ReferenceType.java:625)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getDirectSupertypes(ResolvedType.java:76)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.TypePattern.matchesSubtypes(TypePattern.java:179)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ExactTypePattern.matchesSubtypes(ExactTypePattern.java:74)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.TypePattern.matchesStatically(TypePattern.java:131)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.OrTypePattern.matchesStatically(OrTypePattern.java:76)
>       at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.SignaturePattern.matchesExactlyMethod(SignaturePattern.java:505)

I am using JDK 1.8 and spring version 3.0.5.RELEASE
Can you please let me know what is wrong?

Comment: Tag 15 refers to `CONSTANT_MethodHandle`, which has been introduced in Java 7, but not used by ordinary Java code before Java 8. This implies that the bcel library is outdated.

Comment: so what is the other option to run with jdk 1.8? do I update spring version?

Comment: That’s what it is all about; you must update. Either, the bcel library individually if that’s possible, or the framework that is using bcel internally. Given the age of software not handling these features, updating everything is recommended. Similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23541532/2711488) or [that Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30313255/2711488).

Comment: Thanks for providing me useful information