# Android: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 19 at 5

Tags: android, java-8, android-library, hotfix, java-assist

We're integrating the Hotfix Robust lib to my app. While running the app we're getting below error. We have set the `compileOptions` to **`Java8`** version and also tried by adding **`Javaassist`** version **`3.27.0-GA`** but no luck.

```
Execution failed for task ':compex_task_runner:transformClassesWithRobustForProdRelease'

[ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 19 at 5
```

Comment: Similar to [the constant type 18](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30320312/2711488), except that 19 stands for “Module”, which indicates that you are trying to process code compiled for Java 9 or newer.